# Which of the Azure Cosmos DB types of database should I use to log simple events from my mobile application?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I would like to set up event logging for my application.  Simple information such as date (YYYYMMDD), activity and appVersion.  Later I would like to query this to give me some simple information such as how many times a certain activity occurred for each month.

From what I see there are a few different types of database in Cosmos such as NoSQL and Casandra.

Which would be the most suitable to meet my simple needs?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Cosmos DB SQL API` for storing this data. It has [`rich querying capabilities`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-getting-started) and also has a great support for [`aggregate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-aggregates) functions.

One thing you would need to keep in mind is your data partitioning strategy and design your container's partition key accordingly. Considering you're going to do data aggregation on a monthly basis, I would recommend creating a partition key for year and month so that data for a month (and year) stays in a single logical partition. However, please note that a logical partition can only contain 10GB data (including indexes) so you may have to rethink your partitioning strategy if you expect the data to go above 10GB.

A cheaper alternative for you would be to use `Azure Table Storage` however it doesn't have that rich querying capabilities and also it doesn't have aggregation capability. However with some code (running in Azure Functions), you can aggregate the data yourself.

Comment: Thanks,  that's a very good idea to partition for year and month.

Comment: If this is a write-heavy application i would NOT use date-time as a partition key. The result is the current period becomes the hot partition and will only get a fraction of your throughput. There are a number of Cosmos DB docs on partition strategy. I would encourage reading these before getting too deep into your design and test as well. thanks.